# Using Xcode with Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am creating a cross-platform (iOS/Android) app using Visual Studio for Mac. When I try opening one of my storyboards with the built in iOS interface designer there is an error: There was a problem rendering the document.

```
MonoTouch.Design.Client.DesignerRemoteException: System.NotSupportedException: Could not parse xml
at MonoTouch.Design.Parser.Parse (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4989/9c529966/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Shared/Parser.cs:220
at MonoTouch.Design.UIKitParser.Parse (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext context) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4989/9c529966/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Server/TypeSystem/Loader.cs:205
at MonoTouch.Design.Server.SessionController.LoadXmlCore (MonoTouch.Design.ParseContext ctx) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4989/9c529966/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Server/SessionController.cs:330
at MonoTouch.Design.Server.SessionController.LoadXml (System.Xml.Linq.XElement xml, System.Boolean freezeMisplacements, System.String[] viewsToHide) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4989/9c529966/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Server/SessionController.cs:302
at MonoTouch.Design.Server.SessionController.LoadFullXml (System.Xml.Linq.XElement xml, System.Boolean freezeMisplacements, System.String[] viewsToHide) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4989/9c529966/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Server/SessionController.cs:211
at MonoTouch.Design.Server.CommandListener.LoadXml (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest untypedRequest, MonoTouch.Design.Server.SessionController controller) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4989/9c529966/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Server/Connection/CommandListener.cs:225
at MonoTouch.Design.Server.Router.Route (MonoTouch.Design.SessionCommandRequest request, MonoTouch.Design.Server.SessionController controller) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4989/9c529966/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Server/Connection/Router.cs:49
```

So I've built the storyboard using Xcode. Now I wan't to interface with the UITextFields and UIButton that are in the storyboard. How do I go about doing this when I cannot edit it in Visual Studio?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Just add the `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` in Xcode by dragging the line and dropping it into the **.h** or **.m** file as normal. Then Visual Studio for Mac will update the changes from Xcode.
2. Check in Xamarin's **.designer.cs** file. These `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` should have been added below `[Outlet]` and `[Action("")]`, like this:

   ```
       [Outlet]
       UIKit.UITextField MyTextfield { get; set; }

       [Action ("btnClicked:")]
       partial void btnClicked (Foundation.NSObject sender);
   ```
3. Now you can get your control or add its action method in the **.cs** file, like this:

   ```
       partial void btnClicked(Foundation.NSObject sender)
       {
           MyTextfield.Text = "Hello Button!";
       }
   ```